# Customize setbound value for viewing original image size

Tags: android

```
image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler,
                (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
```

i want to set bounds value for original image size,how can i set the value for display original image size

Answer (score 0):

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```